# issue in fetching yahoo contact list in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, yahoo

*[yos-social-objc-master](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc)*

I have also the problem with yos-social-objc-master project i found in github. after login with yahoo credential. I always got a page and a code xxxx with below lines
"To complete sharing of yahoo! info with xxxx, enter code xxxx into xxxx"
So, I am not getting that where I should enter this code? And how will it redirect to my application.

So that I can get contact list. I have done R&D on it. but didnt get any appropriate solution. Please help me out,how can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution though with a little overheads.

Steps are: 1> Create a PHP script in you own server (say named, YRedirect.php).
2> Pest the following code in it-

```
    <?php
 $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 header("Location: YOUR_APP_ID_OR_BUNDLE_ID://oauth-response?" . $query);
?>
```

3> Add an URL Scheme in your info.plist file with the YOUR_APP_ID_OR_BUNDLE_ID.
That's it and you are DONE with the authentication problem.

And then use YQL to fetch contacts.